# Administratively spread several Thunderbird per-recipient rules for some users?

Tags: debian, configuration, thunderbird, pgp

I administer several computers that have Thunderbird/Icedove installed and I want to spread Thunderbird per-recipient rules for some users. The rules are stored in a file - `pgprules.xml` in the user home folder `~/.icedove/_profile_folder_/pgprules.xml`.

Is there a way to put these settings/rules in a way that they will be imported by default when the user installs or updates the mail client? I can do that with the OpenPGP settings - under `/etc/xul-ext/enigmail.js`.